# How to specify a string in a string d

Tags: python, list, dictionary, fancybox

I want to specify whether the string `A` Is it in another field or not? For example, if `AB` Was N Print

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but this code helps you check if a string contains another string:

```
string = "Hello World"

if "World" in string:
   print("string contains World")
```